# Código não apresenta o resultado

Tags: c, algoritmo

Meu código recebe como entra o valor de `n`, `i` e `j` e calcula os `n` primeiros múltiplos de `i` e `j`. Analisei todo o meu laço de repetição e não consigo encontrar nada de errado, mas o compilador simplesmente fica parado e não informa os valores.

```
int i, j, n, k;

printf("Digite o valor de n : ");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("Digite o valor de i : ");
scanf("%d",&i);

printf("Digite o valor de j : ");
scanf("%d",&j);

k = 0;

printf("Os %d primeiros multiplos de %d e %d sao : ",n,i,j);

while (k < n){
    if (k % i == 0 || k % j == 0 || (k % i == 0 && k % j == 0){
        printf("%d \t",k);
        k++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem erro de sintaxe aí, então o compilador apresenta erro, não fica travado. O código tem vários erros até de interpretação, pelo menos pelo que dá para inferir pelas mensagens contidas nele, e é mais complexo do que deveria.

O que deu para entender é que deve aprender tantos resultados quantos forem indicados em `n`. Então precisa ter um contador para controlar quando chega nessa condição., e isso é feito com a variável `k`. Porém para controlar o andamento dos números precisa andar de 1 em 1, então precisa de uma outra variável para controlar o passo a passo. Isso claramente funciona melhor com um `for`.

Para achar um múltiplo basta usar aritmética, não precisa usar esse monte de operador, o que provavelmente provoca um erro dew lógica e talvez a aplicação fica em laço infinito.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j, n;
    printf("Digite o valor de n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Digite o valor de i: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("Digite o valor de j: ");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    printf("Os %d primeiros multiplos de %d e %d sao : ", n, i, j);
    for (int c = 0, k = 0; k < n; c++) {
        if (c % (i * j) == 0) {
            printf("%d \t", c);
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9sCOhW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/sjjdhbni-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/NMultiples.c).

Comment: Obrigado amigo, eu tinha feito com um laço for anteriormente mas so tinha usado uma única variável que era o k, logo ele n executava corretamente, ai acabei indo para o while. Não tinha pensado nessa possibilidade de duas variáveis.