# Problema com o cálculo da Sequência de Fibonacci

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um exercício que é para retornar a Sequência de Fibonacci na linguagem C até um determinado número informado pelo usuário. O problema é que o programa em vez de calcular até esse número, ele realiza mais um calculo da sequência. Por exemplo, eu digitei que quero até o número 50 e ele cálculo até 55, se eu digito que quero até o número 10 ele calcula até 13.

```
void calculoFibonacci(int);

int main(){

  int numeroFinal;

  printf("Digite ate que numero voce deseja calcular : ");
  scanf("%d",&numeroFinal);

  calculoFibonacci(numeroFinal);

 system("pause");
 return 0;
}

void calculoFibonacci(int num){
   int antecessor = 0, sucessor = 1, auxiliar;

   for (auxiliar = 0; auxiliar <= num;){
      auxiliar = antecessor + sucessor;
      printf("%d \n",auxiliar);
      antecessor = sucessor;
     sucessor = auxiliar;
}
}
```

Comment: É o mesmo problema dessa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/449482/101. Portanto você ficou feliz lá porque teve o resultado, mas não aprender fazer. Isso atrapalha sua evolução. Não seria interessante tentar achar a solução para aprender de verdade em vez de obter o resultado?

Comment: Eu já tentei colocar mais um contado na questão, mas ele retorna o mesmo resultado do que eu estou fazendo.

Comment: Eu fiz  for (auxiliar = 1; auxiliar <= num; auxiliar = auxiliar + antecessor ){
  //auxiliar = auxiliar + antecessor;
  printf("%d \n",auxiliar);
  antecessor = sucessor;
  sucessor = auxiliar;
 }

Comment: Achei o resultado, mas não sei qual a diferença entre o que eu estava fazendo antes, e o que eu estou fazendo agora.

Answer (score -1):

basicamente o problema é na ultima execução do for, como o sua condição pro for acabar depende de um calculo e não apenas o incremento de um por um, pode ocorrer  do calculo ultrapassar a condição, por exemplo:

```
for(auxiliar = 0; 34 <= 50;) //verdade
    auxiliar = 21 + 34;
    printf("55");
```

ou seja tem q parar o laço caso for maior q o `num`, nesse caso usa uma `if(...) break`

```
    while(auxiliar <= num)
    {
        antecessor = sucessor;
        sucessor = auxiliar;
        auxiliar = antecessor + sucessor;
        if(auxiliar > num) break;
        printf("%d \n", auxiliar);

    }
```

Comment: Fiz o teste e não ta funcionando

Comment: peguei a parte errada aq, malz (e estranho n ter funcionado aquele, aq testei com 2 compitalador e funciono)